# Concept and meaning of immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, manifolds

Who can explain concept and meaning of "Immersion" maps, very easy and useful? thanks for advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ M $ and $ N $ be two manifolds and suppose $ \dim M \leq \dim N $. An immersion of $ M $ into $ N $ is a smooth map $ f: M \rightarrow N $ such that its differential map $ df_p: T_p(M)\rightarrow T_f(p)(N) $ is injective for every point $ p \in M $. Note that $ f $ is not injective in general. If an immersion $ f $ is also an homeomorphism onto its image, then it is called embedding. On the other hand you can find this answer in any basic book of differential geometry, so i don't know if this answer is what you are looking for.